# Plotting the Jacobi Elliptic functions

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I have a function

$$f(x) = a_2 + (a_3 - a_2)\text{cn}^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{a_3 - a_1}}{\sqrt2};m \right)$$

Where $m$ is the *modulus*, given by $m = (a_3-a_2)/(a_3-a_1)$.

How can I plot this function in Mathematica? I tried but can't get past an error.

```
m = (a3 - a2)/(a3 - a1)
f[a] = a2*(a3 - a2) JacobiCN[Sqrt[a3 - a1]/Sqrt[2], m];
Plot[f[a], {m, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question and add the code you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please post the right code about your function `f`.

Comment: just passing by to stress that what @cvgmt asks is important

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you call something a function of $x$, $f(x)$, but there is no $x$-dependence.

The way to code your function is the following

```
f[a1_, a2_, a3_] := 
 a2 + (a3 - a2) JacobiCN[Sqrt[(a3 - a1)/2], Mod[a3 - a2, a3 - a1]]^2
```

So, you have a function of the `a1`, `a2` and `a3`. I am assuming the simple range `0` to `1` for all three of those.

In order to plot it for various values you can try the following:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[f[a1, a2, a3], {a1, 0, 1}, {a2, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], {a3, 0, 1}]
```

[image: gif]

Another way to plot is the following:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@Table[f[a1, a2, a3], {a1, {0, 1, 0.1}}], {a2, 0, 
  1}, {a3, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image: a2]

And another way to plot the function

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[f[a1, a2, a3], {a1, 0, 2}, {a2, -1, 2}, 
  Mesh -> Full], {a3, -2, 3}]
```

[image: gif2]

Comment: Nice, how would I plot those symbolically, i.e., without passing values?

Comment: @jimbob97 not really sure what you mean. How would you plot something without assigning values to the coordinates? If you are worried about the ranges, you can of course increase them, or maybe I misunderstood

Comment: @jimbob97 I made it more concrete with a second way of plotting and also showing how the first plot behaves in a notebook. perhaps you can have a look at the updated version.

Comment: @jimbob97 In your code, `{m, 0, 1}` mean that `0<=(a3 - a2)/(a3 - a1)<=1` instead of `0<=a1<=1, 0<=a2<=1,0<=a3<=1`, please clarify this.

Comment: @cvgmt you should also keep in mind that `m` is `Mod`. at least this is what was written in the OP and that's why I passed it like this in this answer.

Comment: @krc But `a2 + (a3 - a2) JacobiCN[Sqrt[(a3 - a1)/2], Mod[a3 - a2, a3 - a1]]^2` is not equal to `a2*(a3 - a2) JacobiCN[Sqrt[a3 - a1]/Sqrt[2], m]`

Comment: @cvgmt I understand that, but I wrote the relation in the first form the post that contained only $f(x)$ in math mode and no code at all. Now, we have one relation in math mode and another in code if you look closely the OP. There's also a square missing and a sum that became a product.

Comment: @krc   I think we cann't use `Mod` in the function,the two functions are not equal `f[a1_, a2_, a3_] = 
 a2 + (a3 - a2) JacobiCN[Sqrt[(a3 - a1)/2], Mod[a3 - a2, a3 - a1]]^2;
g[a1_, a2_, a3_] = 
 a2 + (a3 - a2) JacobiCN[Sqrt[a3 - a1]/Sqrt[2], (a3 - a2)/(a3 - a1)]^2`.  `modulus` is not the meaning of `Mod`

Comment: @cvgmt perhaps you are right. Now I am 100% confused. In any case, I am uncertain which formula is the right one, but I am certain that for something similar to what the author of the OP wanted, I managed to plot in a number of ways :-)